# Qt - How to work around QScroller maximum size limitation (16777215 pixels)

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, graphics, waveform

I'm working on a Qt application in which a user has the ability to inspect an audio waveform. Given a typical 44.1kHz sampled wave, the requirement that the waveform be zoomable to at least 10 pixels per sample, and the maximum width of a QWidget, this limits my waveform to 38 seconds in length (16777215/44100/10). But in my application, the waveform could be upwards of 10 minutes in length.

Now obviously, a user will never be able to view the entire waveform on one display when zoomed in this far. That's why I put it inside a (horizontal) QScrollArea. The waveform widget has a custom paint event which allows it to selectively render the visible portion on screen, so it is capable of handling any theoretical width. But the QScrollArea barfs upon such sizes.

So how do I make a scroller that can handle large dimensions?

---

Here's an image of my application to help you visualize the problem (note that the waveform is supposed to appear pixelated, as it does):

[image: zoomed-in waveform]

Here's the exact error message I receive when calling `setFixedSize` on my widget:

```
QWidget::setMinimumSize: (/ui::SamplerView) The largest allowed size is (16777215,16777215)
QWidget::setMaximumSize: (/ui::SamplerView) The largest allowed size is (16777215,16777215)
```

Answer (score 2):

fake it: use a horizontal scrollbar as a slider and let the widget do some custom painting taking into account the scrollbar position (connected to the valueChanged signal)

Comment: Proposed method will change the scrolling behavior: general scrolling vs kinetic scrolling. If the author is ok with it, than this can work.

Comment: Hmm. This is a possible solution. I'll have to look into whether or not a QScrollBar can handle a larger range. I imagine it can, as the documentation mentions no limitations (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractslider.html#setRange)

Comment: You can scale scrolling. I'm sure that you don't need such big resolution of scrolling.